# When working with GSON is it mandatory to have classes for JSON objects that are needed to be excluded?

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson, deserialization

I am trying to use GSON in order to parse a JSON that include some classes and fields that need to be excluded. Do I have to create classes for such objects, and include such fields in classes I create?

Answer (score 1):

As it take `Class<object> classOfT` as parameter so we have to pass parameter, but if you dont want to make your custom class you can use it by this way.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.fromJson("Response Json String", Object.class);
```

and you can play with that object in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Expose` annotation for your fields with `serialize` and `deserialize`parameters to `false`

Answer (score 0):

Just don't add the field to the class and ignore it. There is no need to use all input, even with auto-mapping. Whatever has no `@SerializedName` annotation will not be mapped- `@Expose` also controls that. But the actual beauty of GSON is parsing such nested nodes to classes of various types.

just see: [@SerializedName](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html), [@Expose](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.html).